# C# Regex how to extract first, second and last part of a string

Tags: c#, regex

My c# regex is

```
^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<type>\w+)\s(?<body>.+?)((?<colorcode>[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{1})?|(?<colorcode>[A-Z]{2})?)$
```

and the sample text is

```
123456 TYPLV Black Body BK
123456 SAMP Body Black BK_V
123456 TCVERC Black BK_V
INVALID DATA TCVERC Black BK_V
```

I am expecting

```
productno: 123456; type: TYPLV; colorcode: BK
productno: 123456; type: SAMP; colorcode: BK
productno: 123456; type: TCVERC; colorcode: BK
productno: ; type: ; colorcode:
```

Note:-
The first part is only valid if it is numeric and should not match if not a number with 6 digit.

Basically i just need the sno , type and code from the above sample. How to achieve this using c# regex. What is wrong with my regex.

My regex works only for

```
123456 SAMP Black BK_V
```

and not for

```
123456 SAMP BK_V
```

Thanks

Comment: Your sample text doesnt match with the regex at all as you are having tags in the regex, e.g. `<body>`. Please provide an actual sample text.

Comment: This happens because of the lazy `body` part. You need to make that part greedy, e.g. using a tempered greedy token. Try `^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<type>\w+)\s(?<body>(?:(?![A-Z]{2}).)*)(?<colorcode>[A-Z]{2}(?:_[A-Z])?)?$`

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Those are [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

Comment: @juharr Didn't know about such a feature, thanks.

Comment: I don' t know why people insist on writing complicated regex for parsing text.  Linq is very slow and uses lots of memory when reading an entire file and try to parse into objects.   It is much more efficient to read one line at a time and is much simpler.  You can always parse the one line with regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks. It works. But the colorcode is not getting the right value i.e if the text is 123456 TYPEEE BKKC TECE AB_C it is not retrieving the colorcode as AB instead bringing back AB_C

Comment: If you keep the same regex for `colorcode` you had, [here is the demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3cproductno%3e%5cd%7b6%7d)%5cs(%3f%3ctype%3e%5cw%2b)%5cs(%3f%3cbody%3e(%3f%3a(%3f!%5cb%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d(%3f%3a%5cb%7c_)).)*)((%3f%3ccolorcode%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d_%5bA-Z%5d%7b1%7d)%3f%7c(%3f%3ccolorcode%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d)%3f)%5cr%3f%24&i=123456+TYPLV+Black+Body+BK%0d%0a123456+SAMP+Body+Black+BK_V%0d%0a123456+TCVERC+Black+BK_V%0d%0a123456+SAMP+BK_V%0d%0a123456+TYPEEE+BKKC+TECE+AB_C&o=nm). Why should it be `AB` and not `AB_C`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i always need AB and not with _C

Comment: Then why do you expect `BK_V` then? Your colorcode matching part and your requirements do not click. Please update the question with specifications. As you see, there is no mentioning of `AB` or `AB_C` at all.

Comment: Tim Schmelter's is fine but the string can start with digits or sometime it won't. In that case productno=tokens[0] will be not relevant.

Comment: If the first group is optional, why didn't you say that in the question? Please update it so that we could provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(?<productno>\d{6})\s(?<type>\w+)\s(?<body>.*)(?<colorcode>[A-Z]{2}(?:_[A-Z])?)$
```

Comment: `.*` won't work as the last subpattern is optional. Colorcode will always be empty.

Comment: Thanks. But how do i get only BK from BK_V

Comment: @MukilDeepthi I'm not too clear what kind of output you would like. The question specified BK_V should be in the one group colorcode. Please update the question if you would like otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple `String.Split`?

```
string[] tokens = "123456 SAMP BK_V".Split(new string[]{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string productno = tokens[0];               // first
string type = tokens.ElementAtOrDefault(1); // second if available, otherwise null
string colorcode = tokens.Last();           // last
```

Isn't it much better to read? You could add a `tokens.Length >= 3`-check to be safe.

Comment: Thanks but this will not work in my case where the text will sometime start with integers or sometime not.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi: so you want to skip "lines" where the six first characters are not digits?